# Would [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults] cause app to crash?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've gotten a few reports of my latest update crashing on launch from some users.

The previous versions of my app had a `Settings.bundle` where I had a few settings that could be changed.  In the latest version I removed it and the code that retrieved values from it.  I did notice that I forgot to remove a call to `[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults]` in my app delegates `applicationWillEnterForeground` method.

Would calling this cause the app to crash in some cases?  I've not been able to reproduce it and haven't received any crash logs from the users who reported the issues yet so I can't see where it's crashing or what it's crashing from.  Other users who have upgraded haven't had a problem so I'm not sure why it would affect some people and not others.

Comment: If it doesn't crash, there shouldn't be a problem.